# animate window opening with jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, animation

on http://www.tiddlywiki.com/ when you click on a link, you get an animation effect, that positons the content.

the opening and closing effect how is this achieved, would the http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Scale be the correct way to do it?

any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They used the `transfer` effect for that.

You can see that effect here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/